# Error en Django: no such table

Tags: django

Veran, algo me esta pasando en django que ya no se detectan las tablas que intento crear:
Me sale este mensaje de error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 544, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 211, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1543, in changelist_view
    self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self,
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 172, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 72, in count
    return self.object_list.count()
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 369, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 476, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 457, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: ciencia_mensaje
[26/May/2017 17:06:20] "GET /admin/ciencia/mensaje/ HTTP/1.1" 500 174330
```

El modelo que quiero crear es este:

```
class mensaje(models.Model):
    texto=RichTextField(max_length=300)
    usuario=models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='destinatario')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario.username
```

Edito:
Información sobre las tablas en el settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Ademas, si elimino la tabla y utilizo migrate me salio este mensaje de error:

```
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    ciencia | mensaje
```

Tambien observo que al utilizar makemigrations despues de añadir o eliminar la tabla me sale que no se ha producido ningun cambio.
La otras tablas de mi proyecto funcionan.

Comment: Pues ese error no está relacionado con la tabla `mensaje` que estás tratando de crear. ¿Qué base de datos estás usando?,  ¿has corrido las migraciones?

Comment: @César He añadido más información.

Comment: Ya que estás trabajando con SQLite intenta borrar el archivo de la base de datos (db.sqlite3), corre la migración inicial usando `migrate` y luego para aplicar las demás migraciones de tus modelos corre el `makemigrations`. Finalmente tendrás que ejecutar el `migrate` nuevamente para aplicar estos últimos. Me cuentas cómo te va.

Comment: @César ¿Te refieres a que borre lo que he mostrado de settings.py?

Comment: Me refiero al archivo que se ha creado para la base de datos, cuando trabajas con SQLite se crea un archivo que contiene la base de datos, según tu configuración en el settings ese archivo se debe llamar __db.sqlite3__ y debe estar dentro de tu proyecto.

Comment: @César Lo he hecho, pero en vez de solucionarse el problema se ha extendido a las otras tablas. Ademas, observo que en el primer migrate se muestra varios cambios, pero en makemigrations sale que no pasa absolutamente nada.

Comment: Ademas, he comprobado que el shell detecta las tablas incluso aunque tenga borrado db.sqlite3.

Comment: LLegados a este punto. Borra la DB, borra tus carpetas de migraciones. Una vez borradas ejecuta un makemigrations. Te aseguras de que todas las tablas sean creadas, si algun modulo no las escriniera ejecutas: makemigrations nombremodulo. Y una vez esten todas dale al migrate de nuevo

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. Basicamente he eliminado las tablas y la he rehecho.

Comment: te sugiero realizar esto: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html